Lottie animation (lottie-6.4.0.aar) error "ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/Okio" in ATV11 AOSP
We are trying to implement "lottie-6.4.0.aar" library to ATV11 application to AOSP android. App complied successfully but when loading JSON animation file we get following animation. Same error getting in Android Studio also.
19:05:45.846 AndroidRuntime           D  Shutting down VM
19:05:45.851 AndroidRuntime           E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                     Process: com.technicolor.tv.remotepairing, PID: 25850
                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to parse composition
                                        at 
com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.lambda$static$0(LottieAnimationView.java:74)
                                        at 
com.airbnb.lottie.-$$Lambda$LottieAnimationView$_QsjyhNZ7CpKRrGRN9Z59RcnTW8.onResult(Unknown Source:2)
                                        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$WeakFailureListener.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:116)
                                        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$WeakFailureListener.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:98)
                                        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask.notifyFailureListeners(LottieTask.java:179)
                                        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask.notifyListenersInternal(LottieTask.java:156)
                                        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask.lambda$UEMe74LoiWimpRSllfPk_cTR81I(Unknown Source:0)
                                        at com.airbnb.lottie.-$$Lambda$LottieTask$UEMe74LoiWimpRSllfPk_cTR81I.run(Unknown Source:2)
                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:962)
                                     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/Okio;
                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:193)
                                        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask$LottieFutureTask.done(LottieTask.java:201)
                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
                                     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/Okio;
                                        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawResSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:304)
                                        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.lambda$fromRawRes$2(LottieCompositionFactory.java:270)
                                        at com.airbnb.lottie.-$$Lambda$LottieCompositionFactory$kHreHcMxmvmikrk5-OrqBQ8jSUc.call(Unknown Source:8)
                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okio.Okio
                                        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawResSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:304) 
                                        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.lambda$fromRawRes$2(LottieCompositionFactory.java:270) 
                                        at com.airbnb.lottie.-$$Lambda$LottieCompositionFactory$kHreHcMxmvmikrk5-OrqBQ8jSUc.call(Unknown Source:8) 
                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 

In layout we add like below,
 <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/lottieAnim1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="false"
    app:lottie_loop="true"
    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/animation_sample_1"/>

Please help to solve this error.
After adding implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:2.1.0' dependencies the error is solved in Android Studio. We must add this dependencies ? if yes what is the solution for AOSP application (Android.mk).
My android mk file,
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS  := optional
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE  := platform
LOCAL_SRC_FILES    := $(call all-subdir-java-files)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(call all-Iaidl-files-under, src)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := LottieSample
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := lottie_api

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := \
     androidx.appcompat_appcompat 

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES :=lottie_api:libs/lottie-6.4.0.aar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)

include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))

